# Extras advancement, where do the points come from?

Tags: fate-core, extras

I'm typing from my cellphone so my text might seem without format.

Let's assume a PC has a magic sword that moves on its own and it has fight + athletics, and a stunt for flying.

1) During it's creation, do the skill points / stunts come from your personal reserve or should the extra be allocated it's own reserve?

2) During advancement, does the sword improves on it's own or do you need to invest points from your advancement into it?

Comment: Does the sword make any real decisions or is it effectively just an attack that the PC controls?

Comment: It can act on its own but it generally obeys the player commands.

Comment: Sorry to be a stickler, but "generally obeys" or "always" obeys? Is there a scenario where the user could go full anakin and say "slay those younglings" (or whatever) and the sword would say "no"?

Comment: It can be compelled to disobey it's master, but mostly it acts on its own or "aids" the bearer when ot is held.

Comment: great. and lastly, can another character take it or wield it? Could an NPC steal it, that sort of thing.

Comment: The sword has will, it admits the pc as a companion but it can be convinced otherwise. Mostly an ally storywise.

Comment: I'm currently writing an answer with an assumption, but I might as well ask: Are all characters getting some sort of magical gear, or just one?

Comment: In this science fantasy setting, every character had one stunt and 4 skill points to construct and out of character extra, like backing from organizations and such. This character was the only one who introduced a sentient extraplanar entity trapped in a sword.

Answer (score 3):

(The [Fate SRD](https://fate-srd.com/) is an amazing resource, if you're not already aware of it.)

## Sidekicks/Allies don't generally advance, and Stunts require character refresh.

For all intents and purposes, this sword seems like a sidekick. The character accompanied by the sword likely has an aspect for it (or at least, they should), something like "Worthy to Wield the Winged Weapon".

As with all aspects, that will give them the opportunity to invoke that aspect for a bonus/reroll. And sidekicks generally have stress and consequences, without having a clear use otherwise.

Beyond that, you're going to need a Stunt (or several). Maybe you want an Aspect on the Scene with a free invoke, like "Fear The Flyer"; or perhaps gain +3 to Fight once per scene; or attack up to one scene away. Each stunt requires refresh, and these should generally come from the player/character.

---

### Unless.... all of the characters get special things.

In a situation where all of your characters are getting a trove of special equipment, then a separate bank of points should be used, similar to how powers are treated in Venture City (TL;DR - Players get a special reserve of 3 refresh than can only be used on powers).

Then, as the game advances, you can increase this side bank of power/artifact points as you like, without necessarily focusing on how that interacts with standard character advancement.